# Passing variables from a form to a function in sencha touch

Tags: php, javascript, html, xml, xsi

I'm working with a sencha touch on a login page, I currently have this function which passes these parameters to a webservice:

```
function Authenticate(username, password, theCallBack)
{
method = "Authenticate";

parameters = "<username xsi:type='xsd:string'>username</username><password xsi:type='xsd:string'>password</password><date xsi:type='xsd:date'>2009-06-05 12:15:00</date>";

// $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
edarah_getDataFromWebService(method, parameters, theCallBack);
}
```

my problem is that in this line:

```
<username xsi:type='xsd:string'>username</username><password xsi:type='xsd:string'>password</password><date xsi:type='xsd:date'>2009-06-05 12:15:00</date>
```

the input parameters(username,password) are passed as pure strings to the webservice, I want them to be passed as variables so that when the user inputs a string, these variables contain the content of what the user typed(the values of these parameters are taken from a webform and entered into this function as parameters).

when I enter a username and password that match an entry in my database, like this:

```
<username xsi:type='xsd:string'>user123</username><password xsi:type='xsd:string'>1234</password><date xsi:type='xsd:date'>2009-06-05 12:15:00</date>
```

it works and I get the desired response, but i'm unable to input them as strings.
anybody has an idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's much simpler than I thought, I wasn't able to do this because of my lack of experience apparently, here's the solution:

```
parameters = "<username xsi:type='xsd:string'>" + username + "</username><password xsi:type='xsd:string'>" + password + "</password><date xsi:type='xsd:date'>" + datetime + "</date>"
```